# Is there a file that states which services are enabled/disabled for systemctl?

Tags: linux, apache, centos7, systemctl

**CONTEXT**

I'm a Linux newbie and I've been exploring CentOs 7.

**PROBLEM**

I'm having troubles understanding where does Systemd keeps track of the enabled and disabled services.

You can pick as example httpd.

Where can I see if httpd is enabled or disabled without using systemctl status httpd? In which file this information can be found?

I have searched in /lib/systemd/system/httpd.service and also in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf but didn't find something like enabled=no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd doesn't maintain any "database" of disabled and enabled service. *It just uses symlinks in target directories to determine whether service is enabled or not*. E.g. when you enable service a symlink to systemd unit file is created in `/etc/systemd/system/` target subdirectory (usually `multi-user.target.wants`). Calling `systemctl disable ...` just removes that symlink.

For system vendor shipped units it is a little more tricky as those symlinks aren't under your control (not sure if that is case of `httpd`). To disable those services a symlink pointing to `/dev/null` named as system service unit must be created in `/etc/systemd/system/...` to "shadow" a real service link somewhere in `/lib/systemd...` by higher priority faux link in `/etc/systemd...`. I am not sure if just bare `systemctl disable <vendor-unit>` does this.

Function of `enable` and `disable` is described here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#enable%20UNIT%E2%80%A6